# ngbrating fires rateChanged on initialization

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I have a `ngbrating` inside a `*ngIf` div, but when the observable `selectedDish$` gets initialized, `rateChanged` fires. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
<div *ngIf="selectedDish$ | async as selectedDish">
  <ngb-rating [starTemplate]="t" max="10" rate="{{ selectedDish.rating }}" (rateChange)="rateChanged(selectedDish.dishName, $event)"></ngb-rating>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding 1 more condition to the `*ngIf` which its result will be false until the selectedDish gets initialized. That way the `ngb-rating` won't be rendered until it's already initialized.